# LEFT JOIN on table.* as alias?

Tags: mysql

How can i simply return a left join's column values as a separate key in a query?

```
SELECT meta.*
     , post.* as venue
     , venue_meta.* as venue_meta
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta as meta
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->posts as post 
    ON meta.meta_key = '_EventVenueID' 
   AND meta.meta_value = post.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as venue_meta 
    ON venue_meta.post_id = venue.id
 WHERE meta.post_id = %d
 GROUP 
    BY meta.meta_id
```

So i'm expecting all the columns in the post table to return as $response['venue'], but I have a syntax error on the first line.

Comment: you can use an alias only for one column and not for * wild card

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate.

Comment: @JoeTaras So i can't return my left join columns in their own nested return array?

Comment: ...also, sometimes it helps to build up the query step by step and test each step along the way.  For example, start with a select on one table, then add the alias, then add the join, etc.

Comment: @AlxVallejo: Yes, you can but you can apply an alias for all, you can use their original names

Comment: I think this question can be simplified: if I understand it right, it's not relevant that it's a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN or CROSS JOIN; in fact, it's not necessary for there to be a JOIN at all. Your actual question is, "Can I return all the columns of a table as one value in the result set?" Phrased like that, there's an obvious detail: what type or format would you expect that single value to have?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a construct like `post.* as venue` isn't valid and produces the syntax error.

You can use one alias for one column name like `post.id as id`

But you will never get nested results for joins. The select will retrieve rows, which consist of a vector of columns with their values.

The short form of your query then would be

`SELECT *
  FROM $wpdb->postmeta as meta
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->posts as post 
    ON meta.meta_key = '_EventVenueID' 
   AND meta.meta_value = post.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as venue_meta 
    ON venue_meta.post_id = venue.id
 WHERE meta.post_id = %d`

which would give you all the columns from all tables in one row (or array in PHP).
To split that into sub-arrays, the result-set let's you iterate over the result-sets properties like columns names and table names. This might help to build up the sub-arrays programmatically.